# Buffer Overflow Works in GDB but not in Terminal

Tags: terminal, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am using Mac OSX. I have created a buffer overflow vulnerable program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int neverCalled() {
    puts("You got me to be called");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    puts("Name: ");
    char name[64];
    gets(name);
    return 0;
}
```

I also have created an input file containing 88 "A"s (`0x414141...`) and `0x700E000001000000`

When run in gdb:

```
(gdb) run < input
```

I get the output: `You got me to be called` and then a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Meaning that I exploited the program successfully.

When run it in terminal:

`$ ./vulnerable < input`

I get the output: `Segmentation fault: 11` and nothing more.

Why does my buffer overflow work in gdb but fail in normal terminal.

Answer (score 1):

gdb on mac os X appears to disable address space layout randomization

http://reverse.put.as/2011/08/11/how-gdb-disables-aslr-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: Is this a guess or the answer? Sounds logical that this could be the answer of course, but ...

Comment: educated guess, no mac here

Comment: Still +1 for sharing. No Mac here either :)

Comment: Any way to disable address space layout randomization on compilation so that this works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Why 0x700E000001000000? Your exploit seems to be layout-specific, probably out of what gdb prints when typing "p neverCalled".

This is not guaranteed in all executions. As cabellicar123 correctly pointed out, the layout where libraries and executable are mapped in a process are randomized and not guaranteed to be the same between executions.

For some reason it seems that gdb always gets the same layout. As an exercise include "printf("%p"\n", neverCalled)" somewhere in your program and see how the value changes.